# Differentiating the expectated area under stochastic process

Tags: probability, limits, derivatives, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove the following,  where $X_t$ is an almost surely bounded progressivley measurable process:

$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac 1 t \mathbb E \int_0^t X_sds = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \mathbb E X_t,  $$

if the limit on the r.h.s exists.

Proof attempt:

$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac 1 t \mathbb E \int_0^t X_sds = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac 1 t \int_0^t \mathbb E(X_{s})ds= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^1 \mathbb E(X_{st})ds= \int_0^1 \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\mathbb E(X_{st})ds = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\mathbb EX_{t}$$

Due to $X$'s boundedness, Lusin's theorem allows me to interchange the integral and the expectation. Then I use integration by substitution and bounded convergence.

Comment: What do you mean by "bounded"? Does the bound depend on $\omega$?

Comment: I replaced it with almost surely bounded, i.e. $|X_t|<K$ a.s. for all $t$.

Comment: Nothing stochastic here, you are asking to show that $u'(0)=\lim\limits_0v$ where $$u(t)=\int_0^tv(s)ds,\qquad v(s)=E(X_s).$$

Comment: So? $\text{}\quad$